# Rows without a name or email address are imported into database from CSV import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to upload data from CSV into my Modular Rails application, so I created a rake file to easily do that. Here is the code below:

**import.rake**

```
require 'csv'

namespace :import do
  desc 'Import users from csv'

  task users: :environment do
    # filename = File.join Rails.root, '/engines/csv_importer/people.csv'
    filename = File.join Rails.root, 'engines', 'csv_importer', 'people.csv'
    counter = 0
    duplicate_counter = 0

    user = []
    CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      user = CsvImporter::User.create row.to_h
      if user.persisted?
        counter += 1
      else
        duplicate_counter += 1
      end
    end
    p "Duplicate record: #{user.email_address} - #{user.errors.full_messages.join(',')}" if user.errors.any?

    p "Imported #{counter} users, #{duplicate_counter} duplicate rows ain't added"
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
module CsvImporter
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :email_address, uniqueness: true
  end
end
```

**database**

[image: database image]

The problem am having now is that rows without name and email address are imported into my database as well which I don't want. I have used callbacks - `before_save` on the model but I think its not a robust solution to filter out rows without name and email address from being saved into my database.

Thanks.

Comment: You may find [this resource](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+validations) helpful, in particular [this part](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) (scroll down to the bit that says 'presence').

Comment: Yeap, but I need more of a ruby way to deal with it instead of callbacks. Anyway, I got a hint already and marked it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a presence validation in your model, the syntax is very similar to the uniqueness validation:

```
module CsvImporter
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, :email_address, presence: true
    validates :email_address, uniqueness: true
  end
end
```

In your import script, you could also declaratively skip any rows that don't meet your validation criteria:

```
CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
  # Jump to the next row in the CSV because this one is no good.
  next unless row[:name].present? && row[:email_address].present?

  user = CsvImporter::User.create row.to_h
  # . . .
end
```

I should also mention that if it is important that the `:name` and `:email_address` are always present and never null (which is probably true) you could/should add a database constraint to make sure you really can never create a `User` without these fields.  There are some methods of interacting with ActiveRecord objects [that skip the validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations) and so you can find yourself surprised if you use one of these unknowingly and create bad records.

The migration would look something like this:

```
class AddNotNullConstraintsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_null :users, :name, false
    change_column_null :users, :email_address, false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve these validations change your user definition:

```
module CsvImporter
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :email_address, uniqueness: true, presence: true
    validates :name, presence: true
  end
end
```

In this case `duplicate_counter` should be renamed, e.g. `unimported_counter`.